# Is it safe to change ionic.css directly?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to customize the design of my ionic app, I don't know much about SASS, but based upon my research, most people have suggested or are customizing the defaults of ionic through the scss files. Since I don't know much about SASS, I was wondering if its safe to make changes to ionic's defaults through the ionic.css file.

Comment: You may lose all changes if you update ionic version.

Comment: Ooh Thanks :), thats nice to know, another con to making changes through the ionic.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is "safe" as long as you plan to never use sass! If you use sass it will overwrite what's in the ionic.css file.

Having said that, you should really just use sass as it will make your life a lot easier. You don't need to learn anything new to use sass because writing normal css in a sass file will work just fine.

You can then add bits of sass as you progress and pick them up.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @bert, I really appreciate your input

Comment: No worries mate, glad to help!